# What is Lineage In Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, data-lineage

How lineage helps to recompute data?

For example, I'm having several nodes computing data for 30 minutes each. If one fails after 15 minutes, can we recompute data processed in 15 minutes again using lineage without giving 15 minutes again?

Comment: Create a rdd, do a bunch of transformations on it. and then call `toDebugString` on the RDD. You'll be able to see the lineage of that particular rdd.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Everything to understand about lineage is in the definition of `RDD`.

So let's review that :

> RDDs are immutable distributed collection of elements of your data that can be stored in memory or disk across a cluster of machines. The data is partitioned across machines in your cluster that can be operated in parallel with a low-level API that offers transformations and actions. **RDDs are fault tolerant as they track data lineage information to rebuild lost data automatically on failure**

So there is mainly 2 things to understand:

- [How does lineage get passed down in RDDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699530/in-apache-spark-how-does-lineage-get-passed-down-in-rdds)
- [How does Spark work internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691385/internal-work-of-spark/30691654#30691654)

Unfortunately, these topics are quite long to discuss in a single answer. I recommend you take some time reading them along with this following article about [Data Lineage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_lineage).

And now to answer your question and doubts:

If an executor fails computing your data, after 15 minutes, it will go back to your last *checkpoint*, whether it's from the *source* or *cache* in memory and/or on disk.

Thus, it will not save you those 15 minutes that you have mentioned!

Answer (score 1):

When a transformation (map or filter etc.) is called, it is not executed by Spark immediately, instead a lineage is created for each transformation. A lineage will keep track of what all transformations has to be applied on that RDD, including the location from where it has to read the data.

For example, consider the following example

```
val myRdd = sc.textFile("spam.txt")
val filteredRdd = myRdd.filter(line => line.contains("wonder"))
filteredRdd.count()
```

`sc.textFile()` and `myRdd.filter()` do not get executed immediately, it will be executed only when an Action is called on the RDD - here `filteredRdd.count()`.

An Action is used to either save result to some location or to display it. RDD lineage information can also be printed by using the command `filteredRdd.toDebugString` (`filteredRdd` is the RDD here). Also, DAG Visualization shows the complete graph in a very intuitive manner as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Spark, Lineage Graph is a dependencies graph in between existing RDD and new RDD. 
It means that all the dependencies between the RDD will be recorded in a graph,  rather than the original data.

Source: [What is Lineage Graph](http://commandstech.com/what-is-lineage-graph-in-spark-with-example-what-is-dag-lineage-graph-vs-dag/)

Answer (score 0):

DEF: The Spark lineage graph is the set of dependencies between
RDDs
•
Lineage graphs are maintained for each Spark application
separately
•
The lineage graph is used to re computer RDDs on demand and to
recover lost data if parts of a persisted RDD are lost
•
Note: be careful and do not confuse the lineage graph with the

Actions force the evaluation of all (upstream)
transformations in the lineage graph of the RDD they are
called on

Answer (score 0):

In conclusion, the Lineage Graph is a key concept in Apache Spark that represents the dependencies between RDDs or DataFrames in a Spark application. The Lineage Graph helps in fault tolerance by reconstructing lost RDDs based on their parent RDDs and their transformations.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).