# Why joining structure-identic dataframes gives different results?

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Update:** the root issue was [a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-36874) which was fixed in Spark 3.2.0.

---

Input df structures are identic in both runs, but outputs are different. Only the second run returns desired result (`df6`). I know I can use aliases for dataframes which would return desired result.

**The question.** What is the underlying Spark mechanics in creating `df3`? Spark reads `df1.c1 == df2.c2` in the `join`'s `on` clause, but it's evident that it does not pay attention to the dfs provided. What's under the hood there? How to anticipate such behaviour?

**First run** (incorrect `df3` result):

```py
data = [
    (1, 'bad', 'A'),
    (4, 'ok', None)]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['ID', 'Status', 'c1'])
df1 = df1.withColumn('c2', F.lit('A'))
df1.show()

#+---+------+----+---+
#| ID|Status|  c1| c2|
#+---+------+----+---+
#|  1|   bad|   A|  A|
#|  4|    ok|null|  A|
#+---+------+----+---+

df2 = df1.filter((F.col('Status') == 'ok'))
df2.show()

#+---+------+----+---+
#| ID|Status|  c1| c2|
#+---+------+----+---+
#|  4|    ok|null|  A|
#+---+------+----+---+

df3 = df2.join(df1, (df1.c1 == df2.c2), 'full')
df3.show()

#+----+------+----+----+----+------+----+----+
#|  ID|Status|  c1|  c2|  ID|Status|  c1|  c2|
#+----+------+----+----+----+------+----+----+
#|   4|    ok|null|   A|null|  null|null|null|
#|null|  null|null|null|   1|   bad|   A|   A|
#|null|  null|null|null|   4|    ok|null|   A|
#+----+------+----+----+----+------+----+----+
```

**Second run** (correct `df6` result):

```py
data = [
    (1, 'bad', 'A', 'A'),
    (4, 'ok', None, 'A')]
df4 = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['ID', 'Status', 'c1', 'c2'])
df4.show()

#+---+------+----+---+
#| ID|Status|  c1| c2|
#+---+------+----+---+
#|  1|   bad|   A|  A|
#|  4|    ok|null|  A|
#+---+------+----+---+

df5 = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['ID', 'Status', 'c1', 'c2']).filter((F.col('Status') == 'ok'))
df5.show()

#+---+------+----+---+
#| ID|Status|  c1| c2|
#+---+------+----+---+
#|  4|    ok|null|  A|
#+---+------+----+---+

df6 = df5.join(df4, (df4.c1 == df5.c2), 'full')
df6.show()

#+----+------+----+----+---+------+----+---+
#|  ID|Status|  c1|  c2| ID|Status|  c1| c2|
#+----+------+----+----+---+------+----+---+
#|null|  null|null|null|  4|    ok|null|  A|
#|   4|    ok|null|   A|  1|   bad|   A|  A|
#+----+------+----+----+---+------+----+---+
```

I can see the physical plans are different in a way that different joins are used internally (*BroadcastNestedLoopJoin* and *SortMergeJoin*). But this by itself does not explain why results are different as they should still be same for different internal join types.

```
df3.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildRight, FullOuter, (c1#23335 = A)
:- *(1) Project [ID#23333L, Status#23334, c1#23335, A AS c2#23339]
:  +- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(Status#23334) AND (Status#23334 = ok))
:     +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[ID#23333L,Status#23334,c1#23335]
+- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode, [id=#9250]
   +- *(2) Project [ID#23379L, Status#23380, c1#23381, A AS c2#23378]
      +- *(2) Scan ExistingRDD[ID#23379L,Status#23380,c1#23381]

df6.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
SortMergeJoin [c2#23459], [c1#23433], FullOuter
:- *(2) Sort [c2#23459 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(c2#23459, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#9347]
:     +- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(Status#23457) AND (Status#23457 = ok))
:        +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[ID#23456L,Status#23457,c1#23458,c2#23459]
+- *(4) Sort [c1#23433 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(c1#23433, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [id=#9352]
      +- *(3) Scan ExistingRDD[ID#23431L,Status#23432,c1#23433,c2#23434]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joins depend on the structure of joined dataframes, but how you built those dataframes can have influence too. If the two dataframes you join share the same [lineage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751113/what-is-lineage-in-spark), you can have ambiguous columns issues in join condition, leading to what you're describing in your question.

In you first run, as you built `df2` from `df1`, the two dataframes share the same lineage. When you join those two dataframes, you're actually doing a self-join, with Spark selecting the wrong columns belonging to only one of the joined dataframes as join condition resulting to a cartesian product followed by an always false filter.

In your second run, as the two dataframes were built independently, join condition is rightly defined with an equality between two columns, each column belonging to a different dataframe. Thus Spark performs a classic join.

---

### Detailed explanation

As [pltc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3441510/pltc) explains in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69318272/6807769), in your first run Spark does not select the right columns for your join. Let's find out why.

#### What's under the hood?

Let's start by getting the physical plans of `df1` and `df2` using `explain`. Here is the physical plan for `df1`:

```py
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [ID#0L, Status#1, c1#2, A AS c2#6]
+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[ID#0L,Status#1,c1#2]
```

And here is the physical plan for `df2`:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [ID#0L, Status#1, c1#2, A AS c2#6]
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(Status#1) AND (Status#1 = ok))
   +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[ID#0L,Status#1,c1#2]
```

You can see in first line starting by `(1) Project` that **the two dataframes `df1` and `df2` have the same column names and ids:** `[ID#0L, Status#1, c1#2, A AS c2#6]`. It is not surprising because `df2` was created from `df1`, so you can see `df2` as `df1` with additional transformations. So we have the following references:

- `df1.c1` <=> `df2.c1` <=> `c1#2`
- `df1.c2` <=> `df2.c2` <=> `A AS c2#6`

And when you join `df1` and `df2`, it means that you do a self-join. And all the following combinations of your condition will be translated as `c1#2 = A AS c2#6`, which will leave you with the simplified join condition `c1#2 = A`:

- `df1.c1 = df2.c2`
- `df1.c2 = df2.c1`
- `df2.c1 = df1.c2`
- `df2.c2 = df1.c1`

When you perform a self-join in Spark, Spark will regenerate column ids of the right dataframe to avoid having same column ids in the final dataframe. So in your case it will rewrite column ids of `df1`. **So column `c1#2` will refer to column `c1` of `df2`.**

Now your condition doesn't contain any columns from `df1`, then Spark will choose to perform cartesian product as join strategy. As one of the two dataframes is small enough to be broadcasted, the selected algorithm will be `BroadcastNestedLoopJoin`. This is what the physical plan of `df3` shows:

```
== Physical Plan ==
BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildRight, FullOuter, (c1#2 = A)
:- *(1) Project [ID#0L, Status#1, c1#2, A AS c2#6]
:  +- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(Status#1) AND (Status#1 = ok))
:     +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[ID#0L,Status#1,c1#2]
+- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode, [id=#75]
   +- *(2) Project [ID#46L, Status#47, c1#48, A AS c2#45]
      +- *(2) Scan ExistingRDD[ID#46L,Status#47,c1#48]
```

*Note that the four new column ids of `df1` are now `[ID#46L, Status#47, c1#48, A AS c2#45]`.*

And when you execute this plan, as for the unique row of `df2`, the value of `c1` is `null` which is different from `A`, thus **join condition is always false**. As you chose full outer join, you get the three rows (two from `df1`, one from `df2`) with `null` in columns coming from the other dataframe:

```
+----+------+----+----+----+------+----+----+
|  ID|Status|  c1|  c2|  ID|Status|  c1|  c2|
+----+------+----+----+----+------+----+----+
|   4|    ok|null|   A|null|  null|null|null|
|null|  null|null|null|   1|   bad|   A|   A|
|null|  null|null|null|   4|    ok|null|   A|
+----+------+----+----+----+------+----+----+
```

#### Why for the second run I have the desired output?

For the second run, you create two independent dataframes. So if we look at the physical plan of `df4` and `df5`, you can see that the column ids are different. Here is the physical plan of `df4`:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Scan ExistingRDD[ID#98L,Status#99,c1#100,c2#101]
```

And here is the physical plan of `df5`:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Filter (isnotnull(Status#124) AND (Status#124 = ok))
+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[ID#123L,Status#124,c1#125,c2#126]
```

Your join condition is `c1#100 = c2#126`, `c1#100` is `c1` column from `df4` and `c2#126` is `c2` column from `df5`. Each end of equality in join condition is from different dataframes, so Spark can perform the join as you expected.

#### Why this is not detected as Ambiguous Self Join?

Since Spark 3.0, Spark checks that the columns you're using for join are not ambiguous. If you inverted the order of `df2` and `df1` when joining them as follows:

```py
df3 = df1.join(df2, (df1.c1 == df2.c2), 'full')
```

you would get the following error:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Column c2#6 are ambiguous.

**So why don't we have this error when executing `df2.join(df1, ...)`?**

You have your answer in the file [DetectAmbiguousSelfJoin](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/analysis/DetectAmbiguousSelfJoin.scala) in Spark's code:

> // When self-join happens, the analyzer asks the right side plan to generate 
> // attributes with new exprIds. If a plan of a Dataset outputs an attribute which
>
> // is referred by a column reference, and this attribute has different exprId than
>
> // the attribute of column reference, then the column reference is ambiguous, as it
>
> // refers to a column that gets regenerated by self-join.

It means that when doing `df2.join(df1, ...)`, we will only check columns used in join condition against `df1`. As in our case we didn't perform any transformation on `df1`, contrary to `df2` that was filtered, exprIds of `df1` columns didn't change and thus no ambiguous columns error is raised.

I've created an issue on Spark Jira about this behaviour, see [SPARK-36874](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-36874) (the bug was fixed in version 3.2.0).

#### How to anticipate such behaviour?

You have to be very careful about whether your join is a self join. If you start from a dataframe `df1`, perform some transformation on it to get `df2`, and then join `df1` and `df2` you risk getting such behaviour. To mitigate that, you should always put the original dataframe as first dataframe when doing a join, so having `df1.join(df2, ...)` instead of `df2.join(df1, ...)`. By doing so, you will get an `Analysis Exception: Column x are ambiguous` if Spark doesn't manage to select the right columns.

Answer (score 0):

Spark for some reason doesn't distinguish your `c1` and `c2` columns correctly. This is the fix for `df3` to have your expected result:

```py
df3 = df2.alias('df2').join(df1.alias('df1'), (F.col('df1.c1') == F.col('df2.c2')), 'full')
df3.show()

# Output
# +----+------+----+----+---+------+----+---+
# |  ID|Status|  c1|  c2| ID|Status|  c1| c2|
# +----+------+----+----+---+------+----+---+
# |   4|    ok|null|   A|  1|   bad|   A|  A|
# |null|  null|null|null|  4|    ok|null|  A|
# +----+------+----+----+---+------+----+---+
```