# Implementing Dynamic Join in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm working on a use case where in I need to implement dynamic joins in spark scala.
Say for instance I have a base table `tableA` and would like to join with `tableB` and `tableC`. Currently there are two tables to join with, but in future there can be a scenario where in I might have to join 10 more tables. Apparently, changing the code each time wouldn't be feasible.
I kind of worked on the below solution -

```
def joinDataframes(baseDf: DataFrame, 
                   dfList: List[(DataFrame, Seq[String], String)]) 
                  : DataFrame = {

  dfList.foldLeft(baseDf) {
    case (currentDf, (df, joinCols, joinType)) => 
      currentDf.join(df, joinCols, joinType)
  }
}
```

**Input Data**

```
val tableA = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
      (1, "John"),
      (2, "Jane"),
      (3, "Alice")
    )).toDF("id", "name")

val tableB = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
      (1, "John", "New York"),
      (2, "Jack", "Delhi"),
      (3, "Ned", "Bengaluru")
    )).toDF("id", "name", "city")

val tableC = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
      (1, "Accounting"),
      (2, "Engineering"),
      (3, "HR")
    )).toDF("id", "department")
```

**Implementation**

```
val dfList = List(
  (tableB, Seq("id", "name"), "left"),
  (tableC, Seq("id"), "inner")  
)

val joinedDf = joinDataframes(tableA, dfList)
```

As can be seen here, the creation of `dfList` can complicated and is not scalable if the tables and join columns essentially increase especially if it is passed via parameters. Also, the column names for both the base table and the lookup tables differ. 
Is there a better way to handle this use case?

Comment: No matter what you do, you will always have lineage issues when performing these types of operations sequentially. More on lineage here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751113/what-is-lineage-in-spark/45751797#45751797

Comment: Do we an option to handle it?

Comment: I'll start by adding checkpoints inside of the foldLeft function but it will not solve all of your issues. While checkpointing helps manage lineage and potentially improve performance by truncating the lineage, it incurs I/O overhead because it writes the DataFrame to disk. Use it judiciously based on your application's specific needs and performance characteristics...

Answer (score 0):

I concur with the point mentioned by @eliasah. You can implement checkpointing to improve the performance of the long lineage that is created.

Additionally I would suggest you containerize the `List[(DataFrame, Seq[String], String)]` into a case class so that there is readability, type safety as the compiler will catch any attempt to use the value of wrong type.

```scala
case class JoinInfo(df: DataFrame, joinCols: Seq[String], joinType: String)

/**
 * Join the dataframes based on the joinInfos provided and return the resulting dataframe
 * @param baseDf The base dataframe to join with
 * @param joinInfos The list of dataframes to join with the base dataframe
 * @param shouldCheckpoint Whether to checkpoint the resulting dataframe
 * @return  The resulting dataframe after joining all the dataframes
 */
def joinDataframes(baseDf: DataFrame, joinInfos: List[JoinInfo], shouldCheckpoint: Boolean = false): DataFrame = {
  joinInfos.foldLeft(baseDf) {
    case (currentDf, JoinInfo(df, joinCols, joinType)) =>
      val joinedDf = currentDf.join(df, joinCols, joinType)
      if (shouldCheckpoint && spark.sparkContext.getCheckpointDir.isDefined) {
        joinedDf.checkpoint()
      } else {
        joinedDf
      }
  }
}
```

This is comparatively scalable as well, since if you want to add an extra parameter you can do so by modifying the case class instead of adjusting the elements.

You can now use it on the data as below:

```scala
val tableA = // data
val tableB = // data
val tableC = // data

val joinInfos = List(
  JoinInfo(tableB, Seq("id", "name"), "inner"),
  JoinInfo(tableC, Seq("id"), "inner")
)

val joinedDf = joinDataframes(tableA, joinInfos, shouldCheckpoint = true)
```

Here, you are performing the checkpoint when it is enabled in your session. When `checkpoint` is performed on an RDD or DataFrame, Spark saves the data to a checkpoint directory on disk and uses this saved version for future actions. This means that the next time an action is performed on the RDD or DataFrame, Spark doesn't need to compute the entire lineage, but only the transformations that were applied after the checkpoint.

Comment: But still I presume, the overhead of creating the `joinInfos` would be there right? Idea is to minimise this overhead especially when `joinInfos` is passed via parameters. Is that possible anyhow?

Comment: Are you concerned about the size of the list or the tediousness in creating a list of all tables, columns, type of join? You can write an utility to create the joinInfos List in that case as well.

Comment: I'm concerned about the list size as well as different columns for both `baseDf` and the joining tables

Comment: You can try using a `Seq` data structure if you're concern is about the performance as the number of tables increases (say 100 tables joined with base table). If the concern is about creating the list itself, then I would suggest you to create an utility that can generate the list `joinInfos` dynamically, instead of doing it in line.