# Word count using Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

i have to write a program in Scala, using spark which counts how many times a word occours in a text, but using the RDD my variable count always displays 0 at the end. Can you help me please?
This is my code

```
import scala.io.Source
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object wordcount {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      // set spark context
      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wordcount").setMaster("local[*]")
      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

      val distFile = sc.textFile("bible.txt")

      print("Enter word to loook for in the HOLY BILE: ")
      val word = Console.readLine
      var count = 0;
      println("You entered " + word)

      for (bib <- distFile.flatMap(_.split(" "))) {

        if (word==bib) {
            count += 1

        }

      }  
      println(word + " occours " + count + " times in the HOLY BIBLE!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to use available transformations in RDD instead of your own program (though its not harm) to get the desired result, for example following code could be used to retrieve the word count.

```
val word = Console.readLine
println("You entered " + word)
val input = sc.textFile("bible.txt")
val splitedLines = input.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
                    .filter(x => x.equals(word))

System.out.println(splitedLines.count())
```

Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691385/internal-work-of-spark/30691654#30691654) for more information about the internals of Spark.

Comment: Downvoted only because the for block will result in a `foreach` so stating that no action is called is incorrect.

Comment: @Justin Pihony, I see you are right, so i removed my comments about the RDD actions. Thank you for point that out.

Comment: I've got one more problem. I made the JAR of the program and i want to run it in spark over hadoop in the google cloud platform but I get the error that ClassNotFound even if it works when i play it in local in the spark stanalone. Can you help me please? thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using a mutable variable on a distributed set. This is hard to control in normal situations, and especially in Spark, the variable is copied separately to each worker. So, they end up with their own version of the `count` variable and the original is actually never updated. You would need to use an [`accumulator`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators), which is only guaranteed for actions. All that said, you can accomplish this without variables or accumulators:

```
val splitData = distFile.flatMap(_.split(" "))
val finalCount = splitData.aggregate(0)(
  (accum, word) => if(word == bib) accum + 1 else accum,
  _ + _)
```

What this is doing is first seeding the count with a 0. Then, the first operation is what will be run on each partition. The `accum` is the accumulated count and the `word` is the current word to compare. The second operation is simply the combiner used to add all of the partition's `count`s together.

Comment: Where do I have to put the code? inside the for? btw thanks for your answer man

Comment: You would get rid of the for altogether and put this in its place.

Answer (score 1):

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("demoscala.txt")
val counts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
counts.saveAsTextFile("WordCountSpark")
```

If anyone is confused of (_).Good blog below

http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/quick-explanation-of-scalas-syntax

Answer (score 0):

I think that the iteration : `bib <- distFile.flatMap(_.split(" "))` won't work, because your data is in the RDD, try to do a collect like :

`for (bib<-distFile.flatMap(_.split(" ")).collect)`.

(it works just in case of your data are not huge, and you can make a collect on it)

otherwise, if your data set is huge you can do like :

```
val distFile = sc.textFile("bible.txt")
val word = Console.readLine
val count = distFile.flatMap(_.split(" ")).filter(l=>l==word).count
println(word + " occours " + count + " times in the HOLY BIBLE!")
```

Comment: What if the data is too large to collect onto the driver? This does not solve this from a big data perspective. It just turns it back into a single threaded, one machine problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
val text=sc.textfile("filename.txt")

val counts=text.flatmap(line=>line.split("")).map(word=>(word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_) counts.collect
```

Comment: Hi... Explaining your solution would be helpful