# How to change the column type from String to Date in DataFrames?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe that have two columns (C, D) are defined as string column type, but the data in the columns are actually dates. for example column C has the date as "01-APR-2015" and column D as "20150401" I want to change these to date column type, but I didn't find a good way of doing that. I look at the stack overflow  I need to convert the string column type to Date column type in Spark SQL's DataFrame. the date format can be "01-APR-2015" and I look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383107/how-to-change-column-types-in-spark-sqls-dataframe) but it didn't have info relate to date

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.2**

You can use `to_date`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{to_date, to_timestamp}

df.select(to_date($"ts", "dd-MMM-yyyy").alias("date"))
```

or `to_timestamp`:

```
df.select(to_date($"ts", "dd-MMM-yyyy").alias("timestamp"))
```

with intermediate `unix_timestamp` call.

**Spark < 2.2**

Since Spark 1.5 you can use `unix_timestamp` function to parse string to long, cast it to timestamp and truncate `to_date`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{unix_timestamp, to_date}

val df = Seq((1L, "01-APR-2015")).toDF("id", "ts")

df.select(to_date(unix_timestamp(
  $"ts", "dd-MMM-yyyy"
).cast("timestamp")).alias("timestamp"))
```

**Note**:

Depending on a Spark version you this may require some adjustments due to [SPARK-11724](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11724):

> Casting from integer types to timestamp treats the source int as being in millis. Casting from timestamp to integer types creates the result in seconds.

If you use unpatched version `unix_timestamp` output requires multiplication by 1000.

Comment: My edit has been rejected but I'm pretty sure there is a "}" missing in your first import line and you wrote "to_date" instead of "to_timestamp" line 7

Comment: Getting the error - `<console>:28: error: too many arguments for method to_date: (e: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Column`