# udf Function for DataType casting, Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, types

I have next DataFrame:

```
df.show()

+---------------+----+
|              x| num|
+---------------+----+
|[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]|   0|
|[0.3, 0.1, 0.1]|   1|
|[0.2, 0.1, 0.2]|   2|
+---------------+----+
```

This DataFrame has follow Datatypes of columns:

```
df.printSchema 
root
 |-- x: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- num: long (nullable = true)
```

I try to convert currently the DoubleArray inside of DataFrame to the FloatArray. I do it with the next statement of udf:

```
val toFloat = udf[(val line: Seq[Double]) => line.map(_.toFloat)]
val test = df.withColumn("testX", toFloat(df("x")))
```

This code is currently not working. Can anybody share with me the solution how to change the array Type inseide of DataFrame?

What I want is:

```
df.printSchema 
root
 |-- x: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: float (containsNull = true)
 |-- num: long (nullable = true)
```

This question is based on the question [How tho change the simple DataType in Spark SQL's DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383107/how-to-change-column-types-in-spark-sqls-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `udf` is wrongly declared. You should write it as follows :

```
val toFloat = udf((line: Seq[Double]) => line.map(_.toFloat))
```

Comment: @cheseaus, thank you very much. I didn't know that val is redundant and brackets are false. I just learn now udf syntax und usage