# cast schema of a data frame in Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to cast the schema of a dataframe to change the type of some columns
using Spark and Scala.

Specifically I am trying to use as[U] function whose description reads:
"*Returns a new Dataset where each record has been mapped on to the specified type. 
The method used to map columns depend on the type of U*"

In principle this is exactly what I want,  but I cannot get it to work.

Here is a simple example taken from 
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DatasetSuite.scala

```
    // definition of data
    val data = Seq(("a", 1), ("b", 2)).toDF("a", "b")
```

As expected the schema of data is:

```
    root
     |-- a: string (nullable = true)
     |-- b: integer (nullable = false)
```

I would like to cast the column "b" to Double.  So I try the following:

```
    import session.implicits._;

    println(" --------------------------- Casting using (String Double)")

    val data_TupleCast=data.as[(String, Double)]
    data_TupleCast.show()
    data_TupleCast.printSchema()

    println(" --------------------------- Casting using ClassData_Double")

    case class ClassData_Double(a: String, b: Double)

    val data_ClassCast= data.as[ClassData_Double]
    data_ClassCast.show()
    data_ClassCast.printSchema()
```

As I understand the definition of as[u],  the new DataFrames should have the following schema

```
    root
     |-- a: string (nullable = true)
     |-- b: double (nullable = false)
```

But the output is

```
     --------------------------- Casting using (String Double)
    +---+---+
    |  a|  b|
    +---+---+
    |  a|  1|
    |  b|  2|
    +---+---+

    root
     |-- a: string (nullable = true)
     |-- b: integer (nullable = false)

     --------------------------- Casting using ClassData_Double
    +---+---+
    |  a|  b|
    +---+---+
    |  a|  1|
    |  b|  2|
    +---+---+

    root
     |-- a: string (nullable = true)
     |-- b: integer (nullable = false)
```

which shows that column "b" has not been cast to double.

Any hints on what I am doing wrong?

BTW:  I am aware of the previous post "How to change column types in Spark SQL's DataFrame?" (see [How to change column types in Spark SQL's DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383107/how-to-change-column-types-in-spark-sqls-dataframe)).  I know I can change the type of columns one at a time,  but I am looking for a more general solution that changes the schema of the whole data in one shot (and I am trying to understand Spark in the process).

Comment: I don't think you can - the `as[U]` API does not change the actual types, it just provides a typed API for handling the dataset; `U` must match the actual types, and changing the actual types can only be done via transformations such as `Column.cast` as explained in the question you linked.

Answer (score 5):

Well, since functions are chained and Spark does lazy evaluation, 
it actually *does* change the schema of the whole data in one shot, even if you do write it as changing one column at the time like this:

```
import spark.implicits._

df.withColumn("x", 'x.cast(DoubleType)).withColumn("y", 'y.cast(StringType))...
```

As an alternative, I'm thinking you could use `map` to do your cast in one go, like:

```
df.map{t => (t._1, t._2.asInstanceOf[Double], t._3.asInstanceOf[], ...)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions,  They are very much along other solutions that I found on SO.  Also, they are very much in line with the solutions I am going to adopt.  Still,  it would be very convenient to use as[u].  I am also wondering whether I should do a trick with Encoders,  but then I do not understand why if one use (String, Int) then Encoders are not needed.