# incompatible datasets[CaseClass] when loading from oracle and

Tags: oracle, scala, apache-spark

We load data from oracle into a dataset: like this.

```
val dataset = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
  "driver" -> applicationConfig.getString("oracle.driver"),
  "url" -> applicationConfig.getString("oracle.url"),
  "user" -> applicationConfig.getString("oracle.user"),
  "password" -> applicationConfig.getString("oracle.password"),
  "dbtable" -> query
)).load().as[CaseClass]
```

CaseClass looks like:

```
case class CaseClass (
  RELNR: Long = null,
  INS_CONTACTHIST_DATE: Timestamp = null,
  CONTACTDATETIME: Timestamp = null,
  CONTACTSTATUSID: Long = null,
  ...
```

I want to create a new DataSet[CaseClass]

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val acc = sqlContext.createDataset[CaseClass](Seq())
```

and fill it in a few iterations with filtered data from dataset:

```
 val possibilities = dataset.filter(c => predicate(c))
 acc.union(possibilities)
```

This fails with an error: `unresolved operator 'Union;` From SO I learned that this has to do with incompatible datasets, and doing a `printSchema()` on both datasets confirms that some columntypes are incompatible:

```
Oracle:
|-- RELNR: decimal(10,0) (nullable = true)
|-- INS_CONTACTHIST_DATE: date (nullable = true)
|-- CONTACTDATETIME: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- CONTACTSTATUSID: decimal(19,0) (nullable = true)

empty dataset:
|-- RELNR: long (nullable = true)
|-- INS_CONTACTHIST_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- CONTACTDATETIME: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- CONTACTSTATUSID: long (nullable = true)
```

How can I make the union work? or how can I force the population by the `sqlcontext.read(..)` to use the CaseClass' property types?

Comment: Why don't you change your case class instead of forcing the population by the sqlContext?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan It has crossed my mind by I don't want to modify too much in the existing code, I was hoping for other, less intrusive solutions.

Comment: can you post your `CaseClass` as you posted your `ContactHistoryExtended`?

Comment: The CaseClass was meant as some kind of obfuscation of our business logic. I modified the code, The case class itself is much longer but the disclosed attributes nicely and completely demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I tried to force the schema with `.schema(StructType(Array(
      StructField("RELNR", LongType, false),
      StructField("INS_CONTACTHIST_DATE", BigDecimalType, false),
      StructField("CONTACTDATETIME", TimestampType, false),
      StructField("CONTACTSTATUSID", LongType, false)))).load()` but that fails because of ` jdbc does not allow user-specified schemas.;`
I have the feeling that @RameshMaharjan solution is the only one left :-(

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create the `empty` `dataset` with the `case class` you provided in your question

```
case class CaseClass (
                       RELNR: Long = null,
                       INS_CONTACTHIST_DATE: Timestamp = null,
                       CONTACTDATETIME: Timestamp = null,
                       CONTACTSTATUSID: Long = null
                     )
```

And I tried

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
val acc = sqlContext.createDataset[CaseClass](Seq())
acc.printSchema()
```

But unfortunately I got following error

```
Error:(246, 38) an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion
                       RELNR: Long = null,
Error:(246, 38) type mismatch;
 found   : Null(null)
 required: Long
                       RELNR: Long = null,
Error:(249, 48) an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion
                       CONTACTSTATUSID: Long = null
Error:(249, 48) type mismatch;
 found   : Null(null)
 required: Long
                       CONTACTSTATUSID: Long = null
```

Then I tried

```
case class CaseClass (
                       RELNR: Decimal = null,
                       INS_CONTACTHIST_DATE: java.sql.Date = null,
                       CONTACTDATETIME: Timestamp = null,
                       CONTACTSTATUSID: Decimal = null
                     )
```

This worked with following `schema`

```
root
 |-- RELNR: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
 |-- INS_CONTACTHIST_DATE: date (nullable = true)
 |-- CONTACTDATETIME: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- CONTACTSTATUSID: decimal(38,18) (nullable = true)
```

This matches with your `Oracle schema`

```
Oracle:
|-- RELNR: decimal(10,0) (nullable = true)
|-- INS_CONTACTHIST_DATE: date (nullable = true)
|-- CONTACTDATETIME: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- CONTACTSTATUSID: decimal(19,0) (nullable = true)
```

So `union` should be possible then.

Answer (score 0):

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383107/how-to-change-column-types-in-spark-sqls-dataframe/33423959#33423959) basically nails it down. I modified the creation of the empty dataset like:

```
sqlContext.createDataset[CaseClass](Seq()).selectExpr(
  "ROW_ID",
  "cast (RELNR as Decimal(10,0)) RELNR",
  ...
).as[CaseClass]
```