# Spark dataframe column names not being recognized

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Spark dataframe, df, has the following column names:

```
scala> df.columns
res6: Array[String] = Array(Age, Job, Marital, Education, Default, Balance,     
Housing, Loan, Contact, Day, Month, Duration, Campaign, pdays, previous,   
poutcome, Approved)
```

And sql query on df by column names works fine:

```
scala> spark.sql(""" select Age from df limit 2 """).show()
+---+
|Age|
+---+
| 30|
| 33|
+---+
```

But when I try to use withColumn on df I run into problems:

```
scala> val dfTemp = df.withColumn("temp", df.Age.cast(DoubleType))
.drop("Age").withColumnRenamed("temp", "Age")
<console>:38: error: value Age is not a member of   
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

Above code is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383107/how-to-change-column-types-in-spark-sqls-dataframe).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.Age` is not a valid way of *calling a column from a dataframe*. the correct way is

```
val dfTemp = df.withColumn("temp", df("Age").cast(DoubleType))
```

or you can do

```
val dfTemp = df.withColumn("temp", df.col("Age").cast(DoubleType))
```

or you can do

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
val dfTemp = df.withColumn("temp", col("Age").cast(DoubleType))
```

**Note: `df.withColumn("temp", df.Age.cast(DoubleType()))` is valid in *pyspark***