# Can I change the datatype of the Spark dataframe columns that is being loaded to SQL Server as a table?

Tags: sql-server, pyspark, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I am trying to read a Parquet file from Azure Data Lake using the following Pyspark code.

```
df= sqlContext.read.format("parquet")
   .option("header", "true")
   .option("inferSchema", "true")
   .load("adl://xyz/abc.parquet")
df = df['Id','IsDeleted']
```

Now I would like to load this dataframe df as a table in sql dataware house using the following code:

```
df.write \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
  .mode('overwrite') \
  .option("url", sqlDwUrlSmall) \
  .option("forward_spark_azure_storage_credentials", "true") \
  .option("dbtable", "test111") \
  .option("tempdir", tempDir) \
  .save()
```

This creates a table dbo.test111 in the SQL Datawarehouse with datatypes:

- Id(nvarchar(256),null)
- IsDeleted(bit,null)

But I need these columns with different datatypes say char(255), varchar(128) in SQL Datawarehouse. How do I do this while loading the dataframe into SQL Dataware house?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way can help you modify the column data type, but maybe could not achieve your want.

```
df.select(col("colname").cast(DataType))
```

Here is a blob about [How to change column types in Spark SQL's DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383107/how-to-change-column-types-in-spark-sqls-dataframe).

Maybe this can helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The only supported data types on Spark SQL are given 
 [https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/package-summary.html][1]

String types will in fact be turned into `VARCHAR` with unspecified length.
Spark SQL does not have `VARCHAR(n)` data type.

You should be able to do something like below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df = 
          df.withColumn("Id_mod", df.Id.cast(StringType)) 
            .withColumn("IsDeleted_mod", df.IsDeleted.cast(StringType))
            .drop("Id")
            .drop("IsDeleted")
            .withColumnRenamed("Id_mod", "Id")
            .withColumnRenamed("IsDeleted_mod", "IsDeleted")
            //Replace StringType with Any supported desired type
```

Comment: I was able do it with .format("jdbc")\.
option("createTableColumnTypes", "Id varchar(64)"). But the issue is that I need a column with nvarchar data type in SQL DW not varchar() which cannot be done. Looks like it supports only few data types.